# Getting Sum of an SQL table column until the sum reaches 5000

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am working on an sql query for a table with two columns `Amount` and `Date` which should return sum of `Amount` column values until reaches `5000` and it should also return the value in `Date` column at which `Sum(Amount)` reaches `5000` sorted by `Date`

For example I have the following data in my `SQL TABLE`

```
   ID Amount  Date
    1 1000    5/5/2014
    2 1000    5/1/2014
    3 900     5/3/2014
    4 1500    5/4/2014
    5 2000    5/4/2014 
    6 2500    5/5/2014
```

In the above table the sum of Amount should be calculated after sorting it by Date and should return the sum of Amount and its associated Date once it reaches 5000 mark.

after sorting the data it becomes something like following

```
   ID Amount  Date    
    2 1000    5/1/2014
    3 900     5/3/2014
    4 1500    5/4/2014
    5 2000    5/4/2014 
    1 1000    5/5/2014
    6 2500    5/5/2014
```

The query should Return the following results

```
TotalAmount  Date
5400         5/4/2014
```

The above result is because the sum reached `5000` at `ID=5 Amount=200 and Date=5/4/2014`

May I know a better way to deal with it in `SQL Server`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can use `SUM() OVER()` and just get the first row where the total sum is >= 5000;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, date, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY date,id) totalamount 
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT TOP 1 totalamount, date 
FROM cte 
WHERE totalamount >= 5000 
ORDER BY date, id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82141/10).

Comment: The totalamount 5400 will not be know before, in my question 5400 is where the sum crossed 5000.

Comment: @Dev Sorry, that limit should have been 5000, now it returns the first result at 5000 or more which is (still) 5400.