# Filtering an aggregated Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I request your assistance in retrieving the dates where `sum(count_ID)` equals a certain amount.

```
start             complete        revenue            count_ID

1/1/2016            Yes             $5                  10
2/5/2016            Yes             $5                  20
3/4/2016            Yes             $15                 50
3/5/2016            No              $25                 100  
3/15/2016           No              $25                 70 


select start from table
group by start
having sum(count_ID) = 80
```

Result requested:

```
1/1/2016            Yes             $5                  10
2/5/2016            Yes             $5                  20
3/4/2016            Yes             $15                 50
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the sample table your source data or desired results?

Comment: @squillman sample data.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. To me, you are just selecting all rows on or before 3/4/2016. What is the comparison against `80` useful for?

Comment: Running total problem? Or simply `WHERE complete = 'Yes'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Sum of an SQL table column until the sum reaches 5000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479161/getting-sum-of-an-sql-table-column-until-the-sum-reaches-5000)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `sum` window function to get an accumulate amount in a subquery then get equals a certain amount in main query.

```
select * from (
    select *,SUM(count_ID) over(order by start) total 
    from table
) t1
where total <= 80
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "where total <= 80"? However, this is more like a guess since I still don't get a clear idea of the question.

Comment: Also, it seems to me you need to append "order by start".

Comment: @D-Shih I think you want to add `AND Complete = 'Yes'` as well, in order to match the expected results.